# Locating installation directories on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, package-management, application

Is there any standard way to locate installation directories of applications, installed with aptitude on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`whereis binary` for example:

```
whereis bash
```

would produce something similar to:

```
root@hostname:~# whereis apache2
apache2: /usr/sbin/apache2 /etc/apache2 /usr/lib/apache2 /usr/lib64/apache2 /usr/share/apache2 /usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz
```

Alternatively as root you could run something similar to this:

```
updatedb && locate apache
```

Answer (score 8):

Can you clarify what you're asking for?

**dpkg -L** *PACKAGENAME* will show every file in PACKAGENAME

**whereis** *APPLICATION* will show you the full path of APPLICATION

**dpkg -S** */usr/full/path/to/file* will show which package a file belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

`which` will show you the full filename of a programme.

eg:

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```